Why do we unmap memory right after copying to it
Why do we unmap memory rigth after mapping it? Isn't it that we are holding data in this address?
void* data;
vkMapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, imageSize, 0, &data);
memcpy(data, pixels, static_cast<size_t>(imageSize));
vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory);

Example code from Vulkan Doc
Sorry for this "child-like" question for beginner in cg. Need to clarify it.

Presumably, the mapping is only required during the memcpy.  Once the data is safely copied, the mapping can be discarded.

Presumably the device still owns the memory and can use the info it just received.

It is good practice to cleanup after you're done with something right? This is just like that, you don't need the mapped memory anymore after copying it... so you cleanup and make the memory (on the device) available for somthing else.


Example code from vulkan docs

That's the key element here: they give you a complete example -- map the memory, copy the data, unmap the memory.
Keep in mind that mapping memory will consume virtual address space on your process. This might not be such a big deal in a 64-bit world, but...
As for real-life applications, it's up to the application developer to decide whether they want to keep the mapping (because they want to use it again) or not.


Why do we unmap memory rigth after mapping it?

You don't have to. And you shouldn't.
Example code often employs poor practices. This is one of them.
If you allocate mappable memory, you should map all of it and leave it mapped. Unmapping memory should happen only as a precursor to deleting it. There's basically no downside to keeping memory mapped in perpetuity.
